# Dynamically create columns from rows in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot, crosstab

I have the following tables:

```
"crawlresults"
id  |   url                 | fk_crawljobs_id
---------------------------------------------
1   |   shop*com/notebooks  |   1
2   |   shop*com/fridges    |   1
3   |   website*com/lists   |   2


"extractions"
id  | fk_extractors_id  | data          |   fk_crawlresults_id
---------------------------------------------------------------
1   |   1               | 123.45        |   1
2   |   2               | notebook      |   1
3   |   3               | ibm.jpg       |   1
4   |   1               | 44.5          |   2
5   |   2               | fridge        |   2
6   |   3               | picture.jpg   |   3
7   |   4               | hello         |   3
8   |   4               | world         |   3
9   |   5               | hi            |   3
10  |   5               | my            |   3
11  |   5               | friend        |   3


"extractors"
id  |   extractorname
----------------------
1   |   price
2   |   article
3   |   imageurl
4   |   list_1
5   |   list_2
```

I need to construct a select statement to get columns for each extractor in the extractors table that is used in the extractions table.

Example:

```
url                 | price     | article   | imageurl
--------------------------------------------------------
shop*com/notebooks  | 123.45    | notebook  | ibm.jpg
shop*com/fridges    | 44.5      | fridge    | NULL
```

I don't how much extractornames exists when I execute the select statement so it have to be dynamically built.

**EDIT:**
I forgot to mention that it is possible that I have multiple "lists" in my extractions. In this case I need a the following result set.

Example 2:

```
url                 | list_1    | imageurl      | list_2
--------------------------------------------------------
website*com/lists   | hello     | picture.jpg   | NULL
website*com/lists   | world     | picture.jpg   | NULL
website*com/lists   | NULL      | picture.jpg   | hello
website*com/lists   | NULL      | picture.jpg   | my
website*com/lists   | NULL      | picture.jpg   | friend
```

Thank you!

Comment: Another similar question http://stackoverflow.com/q/7674786/684229

Comment: There is no pivot query in MySQL. In fact these types of queries do not belong to the database because their result is not table per se; pivot transformation belongs to the application layer *on top* of the database.

Comment: @Tomas, check my answer, all you need is a prepared statement and some love. Don't need to bring the application layer on this :).

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly doesn't look like nice general way to perform pivot queries. I think more viable approach is to find some pivot transformation library in Java/PHP/ASP/C#/whatever (similar to `cast` function in R - very simple usage) than debug some complex SQL over and over again :-)

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly I think application layer is exactly where this belongs.

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly and didn't take the note with love :-)

Comment: @Tomas, Ada *Love*lace? (Wink, wink). Never mind, I'm bored today.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for [Dynamic pivot tables](http://buysql.com/mysql/14-how-to-automate-pivot-tables.html).

Code:

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'MAX(IF(pa.extractorname = ''',
      extractorname,
      ''', p.data, NULL)) AS ',
      extractorname
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM extractors;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT c.url, ', 
  @sql, 
  ' FROM crawlresults c', 
  ' INNER JOIN extractions p on (c.id = p.fk_crawlresults_id)', 
  ' INNER JOIN extractors pa on (p.fk_extractors_id = pa.id)'
  ' WHERE c.fk_crawljobs_id = 1',
  ' GROUP BY c.id');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

[Working fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e01e7/2)

---

Basically your original query was generating a bogus `@sql` variable which didn't really extract `data` for each `extractorname`. You also don't need all of those joins for creating  `@sql`. You only need each one of the property names (from `extractor` table) and a reference to the column holding the expect values (`data`).

When in doubt about the structure, write out a simple pivot query for a fixed set of properties. This way it becomes easy to identify the pattern for writing the dynamic query.

```
SELECT c.url, 
  MAX(IF(pa.extractorname = 'price', p.data, NULL)) AS price,
  MAX(IF(pa.extractorname = 'article', p.data, NULL)) AS article,
  MAX(IF(pa.extractorname = 'imageurl', p.data, NULL)) AS imageurl 
FROM crawlresults c 
  LEFT JOIN extractions p on (c.id = p.fk_crawlresults_id) 
  LEFT JOIN extractors pa on (p.fk_extractors_id = pa.id) 
WHERE c.fk_crawljobs_id = 1
GROUP BY c.id
```

As for the rest of your query it is fine, just keep in mind that the `LEFT JOINS` could be useful if there are no `extractions` for some `crawlresults`. Also if your table can contain more than one `crawlresult` per `url` / `fk_crawljobs_id`, grouping by `url` is a bad idea (`MAX` can potentially mix the results from multiple `extractions`).

Comment: When I have an additional extractorname in the extractors table that is not linked in the extractions table it still becomes a column in the result set.
Another concern is when I have one or more lists of extractions. I have edited my question accordingly.

Comment: Jimbo, about the link it is easy, it is a mater of filtering only `extractorname` relevant to that query ([working fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5a8fb1/2)), just update the clause that creates `@sql` accordingly.

Comment: [Masterpiece fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/03a56/11) now repeats single-valued results over multi-valued rows.

Comment: The last fiddle is exactly what I needed. Thank you so much for this! :-)